# Transitioning multiple CSS properties at different speeds with jQuery Transit

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-transitions

Using [jQuery Transit](http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/), is it possible to transition two separate properties at varying speeds on the same element as it is with normal CSS?

For example, how would I go about applying the following in Transit:

```
transition: width 1s, height 5s;
```

I can find no documentation about differing speeds of effects on the same element; only chaining, which is something else entirely (and unwanted). Maybe I've overlooked something or I'm misunderstanding his implementation of `duration`.

Thanks for any assistance rendered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described in the documentation:

> Chaining & queuing: Transit uses jQuery's effect queue, exactly like
>   .animate. This means transitions will never run in parallel. (You can
>   disable the queue with queue: false.)

For further information read about `jQuery queue()` [here](http://api.jquery.com/queue/).

Comment: I realize now that I am asking the wrong question, so you get the upvote and the answer. Thank you for responding.